# Continuously monitor a xpath existence which can get exposed anytime in a webpage

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a java program which runs some selenium tests.

But I have an issue here, where in the mid way of the run, the web may or may not throw a web message having xpath:

```
//*[@id='toast-container']
```

If this xpath pops up, my program stops as the other xPath will not be accessible to selenium
I want the program to keep on running, but when I find this toast-container xpath then it should click on that xpath and continue from where it left.
This xPath may get creep in anytime while running the a selenium tests

Is there a way to find it dynamically? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not a pop-up? My bad.. I assumed it's a pop-up which appears randomly . Deleted my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the @Before annotation to designate a method that checks for the existence of the pop-up before each @Test and handles it if it exists.  Something like:

```
@Before
public void checkPopUp() {
    if (driver.findElements(By.Xpath("//*[@id='toast-container']")).size > 0) {
        //Code to close pop-up
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work. I want that set of command to be running all the time during the program run. Like spawning a thread which will be watching for it.